# Spring JAVA RestControllerAdvice How to get the method name to identify from where the exception thrown

Tags: java, spring

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class, SQLException.class,
      DuplicateKeyException.class })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ExceptionResponse handleSQLException(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
   log.error("SQL Exception thrown from the method name is - ", handlerMethod.getMethod().toString()); //not working
   if (e.getMessage().contains("ORA-00001")) {
      return new ExceptionResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Unique Constraint Violation Exception.",
            request.getRequestURI());
   } else if (e.getMessage().contains("ORA-12899")) {
      return new ExceptionResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Value too large for column during insert/update.",
            request.getRequestURI());
   } else {
      return new ExceptionResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            "Invalid Request. Please contact system administrator.", request.getRequestURI());
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to get the stacktrace from exception. Ex.getStacktrace[0] there you can get the Name

Comment: Can you please provide some sample

Comment: ex.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()